# PHP + Unique an Array

Tags: php

I a table or locations and user query to find there location. The issue I have is some locations are duplicated - below is an example (note: sometimes the result set could be a few thousand records):

[image]

Here you can see:
     Geelong North, Victoria
     North Geelong, Victoria

I can load all the words for each location (without comma's) into an array - eg:

```
 array[0] - Geelong North Victoria
 array[1] - North Geelong Victoria
```

Is there then an efficient way sort the array to remove duplicates. I guess if I ordered the words A-Z - duplicates should be obvious.

Anyone have any advise on how best to go about this. I can picture a solution (kind of like what I've explained above but there might well be a much better way to get this done).

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the words first then apply [array_unique](http://php.net/array_unique)

```
$array = array('Geelong North, Victoria', 'North Geelong, Victoria');
function sortloc($s) {
    $d = preg_split("/\W+/", $s, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    sort($d);
    return implode(' ', $d);
}
$locs = array_map('sortloc', $array);
$locs = array_unique($locs);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a function for that array_unique().
See this: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Other way is, if you dont need to keep numbers, is to put that value also as a key, so:

```
array["Geelong North Victoria"] - Geelong North Victoria
array["North Geelong Victoria"] - North Geelong Victoria
```

That will defenitely remove your dupicates.